# How can I verify a .jar Java applet signature using c#

Tags: c#, java, applet, digital-signature

I'm trying to check if a .jar file is properly signed using C#. I researched a bit but couldn't find a way to check it (much like `jarsigner` does).

I've tried to read the contents of the file and have successfully gotten the *-digest strings from the manifest and the .sf files, but this doesn't really get me anywhere if I can't verify they are the correct signature.

I know this is quite a weird question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to call the `jarsigner` and parse the output of it. Or maybe there is a direct API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment above really does seem to be the best way, that is to call jarsigner as an external process from within C#.  So let me give you some code for that.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class VerifyJar
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "jarsigner"; // put in full path
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-verify liblinear-1.92.jar"; // put in your jar file
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        // Handle the output with a string check probably yourself
        // Here I just display what the result for debugging purposes
        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        // For me, the output is "jar is unsigned. (signature missing or not parsable)"
        // which is correct for this particular jar file.
    }
}
```